# Why does the gradle-clojure plugin skip the compileClojure task?

Tags: gradle, clojure, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin for Intellij in Clojure. To that end I want to implement some extension endpoints with Clojure's `:gen-class` functionality. I've added the gradle-clojure plugin and placed some Clojure code in `src/main/clojure`. But when I build the project it says

```
> Task :compileClojure SKIPPED
```

Why is that?

Also, on a related note: If I add the expression `(throw (Exception. "abort"))` to the Clojure code on the top level, I can crash the build. This doesn't make sense to me. Why would Clojure code get *executed* during the build?

Answer (score 2):

In Clojure, pre-compilation is not required. The source code can be compiled when running for the first time, as long as the source is bundled in the .jar file.

For gradle-clojure specifically, the default `build` task will run `checkClojure`, which will call the Clojure `load` function on each source directory, which loads all the namespaces. When you load a namespace, its expressions are executed in order. Normally you'd only put `def` or `defn` which would just define global variables. This is done to ensure there's no compiler errors before bundling in the .jar.

The gradle-clojure `compileClojure` task will only compile the namespaces that are configured with the `aotNamespaces` or all of them if using `aotAll()`. In that case it will call the Clojure `compile` on each namespace. See the [gradle-clojure](https://gradle-clojure.github.io/gradle-clojure/) documentation for more info.

For more detail about Clojure compilation, see [this documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/compilation)

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting this to work. (Note I'm new to gradle). Following the clojure-gradle documentation I've added `clojure { builds { mybuild { aotAll() } } }` to the `build.gradle` file. But that doesn't do anything yet. What else am I missing?

Comment: Did you follow the quickstart to generate a full gradle project? It recommends downloading the clojure command line tool so you can run `clj -A:new gradle-clj-app myname/myapp`. This will generate a proper gradle project.

Once you have that, run `./gradlew run` in a terminal to run the application.

Comment: Oh I reread and saw you're trying to do an IntelliJ plugin. You'd want to use the clojure library template (the `aotAll()` is still needed for :gen-class which may not be included in the template).